# Browser.document.getElementById("element_name").Value Failing

Tags: html, excel, vba

So, my question is related to a method call that works in one part of the code and not in another.

I have some globally declared things and then 3 subs. Here's the global

```
Declare Function apiShowWindow Lib "user32" Alias "ShowWindow" _
(ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal nCmdShow As Long) As Long

Global Const SW_MAXIMIZE = 3
Global Const SW_SHOWNORMAL = 2
Global Const SW_SHOWMINIMIZED = 1
Dim ie As InternetExplorerMedium
```

And here's the main body. It's made up of 3 Subs, one for the login, one for waiting, and another for accessing another page after you log in. Everything works until the last few lines of the "barcodedetailyesterday" Sub. The exact same method call that works in the "websiteLogin" Sub doesn't work in the "BarcodeDetailYesterday" one. The error is "Run-time error 91: Object variable or With block variable not set". I have tried adding extra delays to make sure it had time to load, I've tried doing everything piece wise, and it breaks down at the getElementById("").Value piece every time.

Does anyone have any ideas?

```
Sub websiteLogin()

Set ie = New InternetExplorerMedium
Const Url$ = "url"
Dim Username As String, Password As String

Username = "username"
Password = "password"
'#####Open Internet Explorer and sign#####
'create IE instance & navigate to login page
ie.navigate Url
Call waitonIE
'use data from Excel file to log in
ie.document.getElementById("fm_username").Value = Username
ie.document.getElementById("fm_password").Value = Password
ie.document.forms(0).submit
End Sub

Sub waitonIE()
'####Wait on Internet Explorer to become stable before working with it####
ie.Visible = True
apiShowWindow ie.hwnd, SW_MAXIMIZE
While ie.Busy Or ie.readyState <> 4:
DoEvents:
Wend
End Sub


Sub BarcodeDetailYesterday()

'open Internet Explorer and sign in
Call websiteLogin
'navigate to page
ie.navigate "new url"
'create time/date parameters
Dim Yesterday As Date
Yesterday = Date - 1
startDate = Yesterday
startTime = "00:00:00"
endDate = Yesterday
endTime = "23:59:59"
Call waitonIE
'insert data into fields
'Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))
ie.document.getElementById("fm_date").Value = startDate
ie.document.getElementById("fm_time").Value = startTime
ie.document.getElementById("fm_date2").Value = endDate
ie.document.getElementById("fm_time2").Value = endTime

End Sub
```

Comment: You don't have a reference to the `ie` object in BarcodeDetailYesterday. You either need to create a new object, or pass the existing reference to the BarcodeDetailYesterday sub.

Comment: Are those fields in an ieframe?

Comment: @RyanWildry I was concerned about that, but the ie.navigate "new url" works regardless, so why would .navigate work but .document.getelementbyid not work?

Comment: Neither should, you don't have a reference to that object unless it is declared globally, but that isn't indicated in the code. Are you sure it isn't navigating in `websiteLogin` and not `BarcodeDetailYesterday`?